# React reveal animation doesn't work as expected : it is slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react-reveal i'm using this for transition. All okay but my transition is quite slow  How can I make it fast?

Please help me.  And tell me how to do some good animation.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! please write the code related to your issue so we can help you

Comment: this is not a tutorial forum ... it is a question and answer site ... please present the code that is failing, describe the problem, describe what you exoect the code to do and ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.